# I am new to classes in python the compile showing error segmentation() takes no arguments

Tags: python

here is my code

```
class segmentatiomn:

    CLUSTERS = None
    IMAGE = None
    COLORS = None
    LABELS = None
    def _init_(self,image,clusters=2):
     self.CLUSTERS = clusters
     self.IMAGE = image
    def dominantColors(self):
        # read image
        img = cv2.imread(self.IMAGE)

        # convert to rgb from bgr
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # reshaping to a list of pixels
        img = img.reshape((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 3))

        # save image after operations
        self.IMAGE = img

        # using k-means to cluster pixels
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.CLUSTERS)
        kmeans.fit(img)

        # the cluster centers are our dominant colors.
        self.COLORS = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        # save labels
        self.LABELS = kmeans.labels_

        # returning after converting to integer from float
        return self.COLORS.astype(float)

img = 'img'
clusters = 2
dc = segmentatiomn(img, clusters)
colors = dominantColors()
print(colors)
```

Comment: `__init__` not `_init_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not define constructor properly. Constructor is `__init__`(double underscore) not `_init_`(single underscore). Just change it and it should solve your problem

Comment: thanks .that was the issue.but now how to return and prnt colors values from function dominent clors